# How to sync Apple Address Book with Windows Live Contacts?

Tags: contacts, address-book, windows-live, windows-live-sync

It seems so easy to sync my contacts in my Apple Address Book with my Google Account, how about with my Windows Live account? I don't have Outlook, most solutions I've seen require Outlook.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no way to automatically sync them, or keep them in sync. The only way to do it is by using Microsoft Outlook as an intermediary step.

1. Export Contacts from your Windows Live/Hotmail account as CSV file (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/import-contacts-from-windows-live-hotmail-to-outlook-HA010224411.aspx)
2. Import your contacts into Address Book.app.

That will be the easiest/best method.

Comment: Argh. So disappointing.  Can't believe there isn't a way to do it.  :-(